# Typescript: Optional data transform which returns different type if used

Tags: typescript

I have a function which fetches data and *optionally* transforms the response to another interface.

I'm having trouble expressing this in Typescript though:

```
type ObjMap = Record<string, any>;

function mapResponse<T extends ObjMap, U extends ObjMap = T>(
  apiData: T,
  transform: (apiModel: T) => U = x => x
) {
  return transform(apiData)
}

// Should return AppUser
const data1 = mapResponse<ApiUser, AppUser>(
  userData,
  u => ({ fullName: `${u.firstName} ${u.lastName}`})
)

// Should return ApiUser
const data2 = mapResponse<ApiUser>(userData)
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwLIEMxQLxQEoQMYD2ATgCYA8AzsEQJYB2A5gDRQp0gB8A3AFA8BmAVzp5gNAnSgBbNLgpgJFCGQAqUCAA9gEOiQqxEqMCwCq6rTr0HkaTFBUcAFDyiswNACIpgKAFz2mFyhqNgp+Yil-RzQaJAISCAAbfxUASkwOKDMsDQyoDR50gG8goghgQSJJELowiOj3Lx9UngBfPgB6DqgAQXcoMoqq-X4aIioAORQpaABqKESUSemIHnptIn4UPGg+mhMlIigS11Hx4CmZ-ypaRiDF5auoG-oGNp4uqAAhQWBggAtoGh0AB3NjAfTAAjBIihcJEKQAmiQ6FCRKJS7QeFQEH-bwQABuECOZSWEjWdA2Wx2vTAYAOxOOQTRGJW12or3ePEItT+MQZRH8ewFdhOUDOjwg-gA5F8CHBpYFXA8LmyoNKAMpSGjAf7Srk8qhQEjeFAARjsMjAcgUtWUwsOLD69MOTiC-Md7vcIowmUcRXFgnRmP8AAMACRFD3EgB0EtVM1aUEj0aIMZVmNaodaLRaH26ADFiM8CDMoARdYyygBHQQQI2VtzoZHi+jQEE6-4A6AUFbSeJJViQwG9AAKAEkY9zFH8TT4AEyW2T121KMgO4lOVOpIA)

The above code produces an error here:

```
x => x
    ~~

Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'U'.
'T' is assignable to the constraint of type 'U', but 'U' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'ObjMap'.(2322)
```

How can I type this so that the

- Return type is `ApiUser` if no transform is defined (we can just use the default transform `x => x`, or none if that's easier)
- Returns `ApiUser` if the `transform` is defined?

Comment: I faced exactly this issue yesterday. How do you have a default identity function as a selector and keep the type-system sweet? I suspect that the answer is function overloading. When I figure it out, I'll come back and post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to have an implementation signature that is not generic. here ou can specify the default value for the parameter:

```
function mapResponse<T extends ObjMap, U extends ObjMap = T>(
  apiData: T,
  transform?: (apiModel: T) => U
):U
function mapResponse(
  apiData: Record<string, any>,
  transform: (apiModel: Record<string, any>) => Record<string, any> = x => x
) {
  return transform(apiData)
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwLIEMxQLxQEoQMYD2ATgCYA8AzsEQJYB2A5gDRQp0gB8A3AFA8BmAVzp5gNAnSgBbNLgpgJFCGQAqUCAA9gEOiQqxEqMCwCq6rTr0HkaTFBUcAFDyiswNACIpgKAFz2mFyhqNgp+YikAfn9HNBokAhIIABt-FQBKTA4oEx5031yhETEJaVkIeUUIZ1c4rx9-XEJSSmp6ZlZ2DkDXELowiJi4hKTUnHxicipaRhY2TkyMbKbJ1pmO+eysDSyoDTyoAG8goghgQSJJPoGiKVj3epR0ngBfPgB6d6gAQXcoU-Ol30-BoRCoADkUFJoABqKDJFAQqEQHj0bREfgoPDQX40ExKIhHIIgsHASHQ-zTdpBBFIilQKmMV48T5QABCgmAwQAFtA0OgAO5sYD6YAEYJEULhW48mii8VCZLJcnQaVQAXc7wQABuEEJp0RElRdHRmOxPzAYHxeqJrkVyuRlLaTLePEI-S5cWtRH8uO9dmOdtBdIg-gA5GyCHAwz14YiyY6oGGAMpSGjAblh5luxRckjeFAARjsMjAcgU-WUfoJLF+VoJTiCXprTfc-qWUEchyg9pV-gABgASQ7NvUAOhJIZeUGHo6IY9pCehL37L2ezxZXwAYsQGQRoVACBmbacAI6CCpc49udBynv0aAC9PcnnQCjI6SJFKsUW8n4ABQASTHHMPSgfMfAAJhLcpKkrMhqz1Jw53SIA)

Comment: Nice! Returning the correct type

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwLIEMxQLxQEoQMYD2ATgCYA8AzsEQJYB2A5gDRQp0gB8A3AFA8BmAVzp5gNAnSgBbNLgpgJFCGQAqUCAA9gEOiQqxEqMCwCq6rTr0HkaTFBUcAFDyiswNACIpgKAFz2mFyhqNgp+YikAfn9HNBokAhIIABt-FQBKTA4oEx5031yhETEJaVkIeUUIZ1c4rx9-XEJSSmp6ZlZ2DkDXELowiJi4hKTUnHxicipaRhY2TkyMbKbJ1pmO+eysDSyoDTyoAG8goghgQSJJPoGiKVj3epR0ngBfPnptIn4UPGgAQXcJiURCOQVc-BoRCoADkUFIIP5pu0wVBkigYXCEVAkYxXjwPhAvj9-mAwEDCaDXODBMlkrD4Yi2ri3jxCP1gFBBMD-ACaOSQVhjlSoBCocB6ViAOQAIQIcElPSpaIxDKgkoAylIaMAABaSvGsxQckgARjsMjAcgU-WUvP5Ti5hOebKoUBIACZzeVKjayHbgSwAWTgQ6A27do5DiKaXTMf5JZKoC90ukgA

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might be the answer... I simplified your code for ease of reproduction.

```
function mapResponse<T>(apiData: T): T
function mapResponse<T, U>(apiData: T, transform: (apiModel: T) => U): U
function mapResponse<T, U = T>(
    apiData: T,
    transform?: (apiModel: T) => U
): T | U {
    const trans = transform ?? (x => x as unknown as U)
    throw Error()
}
```

The implementation might get messy, but the interface to the outside world is consistent.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwIYAcBKBTAzuhXbAHgBUA+ACgxgBFUpUAuRUgShdIChRJYEUGHPkIlSAGkQBVKjXqNOkqACdUYXMDjLkLauhgBZOABNsAG05tEAXnLSO0nuGjwkaLHgLqxkqTdZUXIjBiHIMzKziQSEqahpayAD8ujRGphasVraODqSIAD7SiADe0cEQhFCIser+NfHaiImJiJQAHjZ2Hai4iOAA1mBwAO5IPfZl1QAWyiOIAKLKs8qUbFwAvlwwYFDYysCoENiIAIL6UkTKJZPAMMq4UAByqMjYLA-K2wDmk2Y9Ty83ogPt8NlsdnsDkdTuh0Bc9tcQohQGYzM9Xu8VKDNhV1FUQJcWGcYPCrtZESFbvcARjEAByABCcAARnSoki-g90UC6QBlZAwKBTOlg3EPRDGfzuYReIjEYmkyRnOGXKgEvaSDrZSjFZEgVHclgAAwAJMU2gA6KlcwHrRBmy2cmnYdZGxDrNhsIA)

Comment: Thanks it's close, there's an error that a transform isn't provided diff if given though: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwIYAcBKBTAzuhXbAHgBUA+ACgxgBFUpUAuRUgShdTAE8AoUSLAQoMOfIRKkANIgCqVGvUYtpiKACcuuYHHXIW1dDACycACbYANiraIAvOTkdEXPgOjwkaLHgJgiZDKy9qxUvIgRLkZKzKxS4ZEaWjp6APwGNKYW1qy2DnK8zq6IAN4JERCEUGqa-iFJ-inIiKmpiJQAHvaOXai4iOAA1mBwAO5IfU7lagAW6mOIAKLq8+qUbLwAvoi8vDBgUNjqwKgQ2IgAgkayROql08Aw6rhQAHKoyNgsL+r7AObTSx9N4fL6IH7-LZ7A5HE5nS7odA3I73SKIUCWSzvT7fDSQza7Sr+aogW4sK4wZF3OyoyKPZ4gnGIADkACE4AAjZnxNFAl7YsHMgDKyBgUBmzKhvCJL0QZhC3jEfgCFKpMiuSNuVFJRxkXXyHTYQA

Comment: Confused. Wouldn't the selector need to look like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwIYAcBKBTAzuhXbAHgBUA+ACgxgBFUpUAuRUgShdTAE8AoUSLAQoMOfIRKkANIgCqVGvUYtpiKACcuuYHHXIW1dDACycACbYANiraIAvOTkdEXPgOjwkaLHgJgiZDKy9qxUvIgRLkZKzKxS4ZEaWjp6APwGNKYW1qy2DnK8zq6IAN4JERCEUGqa-iFJ-inIiKmpiJQAHvaOXai4iOAA1mBwAO5IfU7lagAW6mOIAKLq8+qUbLwAvry8MGBQ2OrAqBDYiACCRrJE6qXTwDDquFAAcqjI2CzP6nsA5tOWPqvd6fRDfP5bXb7Q7HU4XdDoa6HO6RRCgSyWN4fL4aCHbXiVfzVEA3FiXGBI252FGRB5PYHYxAAcgAQnAAEZM+KowHPLGgpkAZWQMCgMyZkIJVUQZhC3jEfgC5MpMkuiJuVBJhxkXXylBKaJAGP5LAABgASEodAB0dL5IM2iEtNt5DOwm1NiE2bDYQA)

Comment: @Dominic, not enough characters to tag you in the previous comment 

Comment: Ah yep, but is it returning `any` for you too?:

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwIYAcBKBTAzuhXbAHgBUA+ACgxgBFUpUAuRUgShdTAE8AoUSLAQoMOfIRKkANIgCqVGvUYtpiKACcuuYHHXIW1dDACycACbYANiraIAvOTkdEXPgOjwkaLHgJgiZDKy9qxUvIgRLkZKzKxS4ZEaWjp6APwGNKYW1qy2DnK8zq6IAN4JERCEUGqa-iFJ-inIiKmpiJQAHvaOXai4iOAA1mBwAO5IfU7lagAW6mOIAKLq8+qUbLwAvoi8vDBgUNjqwKgQ2IgAgkayROql08Aw6rhQAHKoyNgsL+r7AObTSx9N4fL6IH7-LZ7A5HE5nS7odA3I73SKIUCWSzvT7fDSQza7Sr+aogW4sK4wZF3OyoyKPZ4gnGIADkACE4AAjZnxNFAl7YsHMgDKyBgUBmzKhvCJL0QZgAjCFvGI-AEKVSqKSjhsZdUzAAmJWiXwSYjq24yK5I26ai2ILr5SgldEgTEClgAAwAJCUOgA6en80HbH3+vmM7CbD2ITZsNhAA

Comment: @Dominic Yes, I just put `any` as the return-type for simplicity. Answer updated to show how to influence the return-type. The `T | U` type is required for the implementation, but only the first two overloads are visible to the outside world.

Comment: Ah yeah cool it's working